# Array of objects values are not displaying in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have array of objects, I will try to display the values through interpolation. I'm getting only [Object Object]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-interpolation-dezhpv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
empData = [];
  sampleData = [
    {
      empData: {
        value: '1122334455',
      },
    },
    {
      empData: {
        value: '6677889911',
      },
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.empData = this.sampleData?.filter((empVal) => empVal?.empData?.value);
    console.log(this.empData);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use function **JSON.stringify**

> The JSON.stringify() static method converts a JavaScript value to a
> JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is
> specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a
> replacer array is specified.

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      convert(data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      }

}
```

**Html**

```
<p *ngFor="let edata of empData">{{ convert(edata) }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing completely the value while looping through the array. Also, I suggest adding a proper data type to your `empData` array, like the following:

```js
empData: { empData: { value: string; }}[];
```

```
<p *ngFor="let edata of empData">{{ edata?.empData?.value }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your *ngFor for this

```
<p *ngFor="let edata of empData">{{ edata.empData.value }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting [Object Object] because an object is not valid input for your html in angular. You need to directly provide the values you want to display. In your case changing the code:

```
<p *ngFor="let edata of empData">{{ edata }}</p>
```

To:

```
<p *ngFor="let edata of empData">{{ edata.empData.value }}</p>
```

Will generate the result you are expecting.

Since you are using angular, you could also have a look at the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to diplay key value pairs of objects directly out of the box.